# Will appengine work in China?

Tags: google-app-engine

A couple of our clients want to know - looking at some posts about there is inconsistent information.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1144

Comment: @Mitch They marked the issue as fixed but I imagine they are somewhat at the mercy of the factors outside their control.

Comment: I'm sure appengine will work when facebook and twitter can be accessed in C.H.I.N.A.   But, can anyone tell me when? @directedbit

Comment: This is up to China, not Google.

Comment: @NickJohnson - agreed but unfortunately it still means we need work arounds for Chinese localization if we choose appengine. I'm not looking to allocate blame, simply to find the best solution.

Comment: How about using an VPN to be able to test it yourself and not really on testers/mixed answer? Maybe this [list of VPN providers](http://www.bestvpnservice.com/blog/best-chinese-ip-vpn/) helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is "**No**", for now and long after.

- of cz google support his service in china,
- but not china gov.
- appspot is blocked by a big firewall around china.

*by the way, it works when Obama visitting china.*

Comment: Love the final comment XD

Answer (score 14):

Based on tests I conducted it appears that App Engine itself is not blocked in China, but the appspot.com domain is. So if you can use your own domain then App Engine should work fine for you. 
In fact, if you use `yourapp.appsp0t.com` (with a zero instead of an o) then it seems to work as well at the moment, although I would not really recommend relying on this work-around in the long run; it opens your app and your users to Man in the Middle (MITM) attacks from whoever runs `appsp0t.com`.

Here are some tools you can use to check availability and performance from China:

- http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/
- http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.china-test.html
- http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/WebTools/website-speed-test.aspx

Comment: By using a workaround like appsp0t (with a zero) you're intentionally opening your app and your users to man in the middle attacks from whoever runs appsp0t.com

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, since Google DNS server is blocked by 'Great Firewall', therefore one cannot reach myapp.appspot.com within China.

However, you can work around by setting up a reverse-proxy server, which redirects myapp.com to myapp.appspot.com.

Answer (score 4):

What about using custom domain name?

This will get around the DNS resolution. But is the google IP address range allocated for appengine blocked by china? If so, you then you have to use the reverse proxy solution.

Comment: I've just tried here and appspot.com looks blocked but our custom domain seems ok (we'll know soon for real, thanks to one customer based in China): http://viewdns.info/chinesefirewall/?domain=appspot.com

Comment: Any update on this would be appreciated! greatfirewallofchina.org shows me green for my naked domain (`example.com`) and red for `www.example.com` - I'm not sure what do make out of this.

Comment: www.example.com doesn't work because you are using a CNAME to a google domain. Setup www.example.com with A and AAAA records just like example.com and it will work fine.