# Running an appengine app in China?

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, migration

I have an [appengine app](http://www.koolbusiness.com) that I'm happy with and I localized it to several countries and languages. Now I want to localize it for China and Hong Kong but I believe that these areas block appengine so that google cannot be used. What is then the best development plan to make my app available in China? Should I change to a different backend (django + mysql?) and deploy it to some Hong Kong or China hosting or is there a simpler way? I use gae blobstore, gae models, the gae search API, memcache, gnu gettext, jinja2 and the gae mail API (but no compute engine). So the best way I can think of would be to migrate the backend to something than can run and get accessed from China and Hong Kong. Or is there a better way?

Comment: I ran into this a while back and AFAIK, there isn't a better way. . . There are [some tools](http://www.appscale.com/) that make moving a GAE to a different hosting solution a bit easier.

Comment: http://capedwarf.org/ and the alternative @mgilson pointed to may be worth a try.

Comment: There is appscale and capedwarf, or you could set up a reverse proxy for your application, which may or may not work well depending on the amount of traffic you expect (but proxies can scale as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different options:

If you're planning on deploying a separate, localized version for China (with a separate data set), you can use [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/resources/use-cases/a-fortune-1000-retailer-uses-appscale-to-run-its-supply-chain-application-within-mainland-china/) and running in a Chinese public cloud (Aliyun is pretty easy to get started with). This ensures accessibility for your users in China, but means that this deployment would function as an isolated, China-specific deployment.

If you want to have users around the globe (including Chinese/Hong Kong users) access a single app with a shared backend, you could:

1. keep the app in GAE and use a reverse proxy (such as CloudFlare) to
   get around the firewall issues
2. use AppScale to run the app (unmodified) in a different public cloud, such as EC2
3. rewrite the app

In my experience, a reverse proxy works is only a viable solution if performance isn't crucial. For a user-facing web app like KoolBusiness, it might pose a few challenges latency-wise. But I work for AppScale, so most of the users I talk with are already exploring options other than reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Proxying your website will be easier than moving to a different host. You could try using CloudFlare for this.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially simpler option is just mapping the app to a custom domain, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093384/4495081.

I see used the http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org tool to check your app and it is reported all green:

http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.koolbusiness.com

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions available according to your budget:

1- Host your servers in Hong Kong. Contact the hosting platform and inform them that you need your data to be available in China, they would be able to host your data on the fastest data center (the one with the fastest connection to Mainland China). Won’t be the fastest option available but it will be the cheapest option.

2- Use Public Cloud providers such as AWS or Microsoft Azure (outside of China) + their respective CDNs. Most of the cloud providers have endpoints in Hong Kong and you will be able to get an acceptable band-with. Will be cost-efficient.

3- Use Chinese Cloud providers such as AliCloud (China branch, not international), AWS China or Azure China. For that, you will need to have a Chinese company established and you may need to get an ICP license (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICP_license if you have public content). Expensive but that’s the best option if you decide to operate in China for the long run.

4- Use your own backend and add a professional CDN such as Akamai, they have an option called China CDN that will help you go through the Great Firewall (budget +/- 10k$ per month). Will be very expensive.